# Is it possible to load requirejs under a different name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, namespaces, requirejs, amd

I know that for design reasons requirejs doesn't offer a way to load itself in noContext mode, bound to a different variable.  Is it possible to do this manually somehow, or does require utilize the specific word "require" to execute its code?  I know that it needs to the "require" and "requirejs" global variables to work - is it possible to change these names?

A little context: I am building Chrome extension which needs to load requireJS on a page to load a decent number of modules.  However, some pages (upworthy.com and slate.com being 2 prominent examples) have critical functionality already bound to the name "require" (in the case of upworthy, they use [requirebin](http://requirebin.com/) or browserify).  So I want to load requireJS without interfering with whatever native functionality is already assigned to require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript execution environment of [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are separated from the page, so you should not have any namespace collisions.

If you really need to [inject the script in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), then I strongly recommend to use [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) to generate one single JavaScript file, wrapped in an anonymous self-invoking function. Then, the `require` variable of your script will not conflict with the one in the page.

Comment: How can I load the requireJS file without injecting it into the header?  I can't find any info on how to load it using XHR...

Comment: Damn Rob, you've answered enough of my questions on here that I should credit you as a code contributor or something.  Much thanks!